# How to use express req variables with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, routes

So what I'm trying to do is when someone loads my site, and gets authenticated by passport, their userId is stored in `req.user.id` in my `app.get('/home', funciton(req, res)`. Now what I am trying to do in a way is this:

```
app.get('/home'. function(req, res){
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('userId', req.user.id);
    });
}
```

Thats essentially what I'm *trying* to do, but I know it is very wrong. Now my question is how can I get the `req.user.id` to the client so I can use it in future interactions with the server.

Comment: I've already told you over in [your prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321922/express-specific-socket-io-connections-per-page) that the info has to come from cookie/session.  If you tell use where `req.user.id` comes from in your `app.get()` request (you probably have some middleware that is doing that from a session/cookie), then we can help you better.  You need to include more of your code that handles authenticating and setting user credentials and THEN and only then can we help you figure out how to get access to that from socket.io.

Comment: This is mighty close to a dup of your [prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321922/express-specific-socket-io-connections-per-page), but you don't seem to like the answer to the previous question so it seems you're just trying again.  The answer is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're receiving a GET request and using Express right? You're probably passing the userid in the querystring, so you'll want to use:

```
req.query.userid
```

This basically pulls the value assigned to a key in the querystring.

Source: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

I would also recommend sending something like ?userid=12345 in the querystring, rather than an object (user.id) in the querystring, as encoding an object will unnecessarily add more complications and not needed.

Comment: This seems like the way to go, but how could i possibly secure this. What is stoping someone from just changing their url and getting other people's stuff. Im unsure as to how to secure that

Comment: Also the way I would use this is by pulling the querystring on the client side?

Comment: To your first question, that's a whole other topic requiring authentication (basically when a user signs in the server gives the client a "token" only that client would know, and then sends that token on every request) here's a good intro tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Your second question, your client-side would be sending the GET request with the querystring.  Not sure what framework you are using client-side, but you can look up how to format your querystring the right way that your server can handle

Answer (score 0):

You can use express session with socket.io
There's a npm module called express-socket.io-session